# Create file failed from mkdir()

Tags: android, mkdir

I try to create file in my android emulator, but when i finish my code.
I can't find the file i create from android device monitor.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        System.out.println("can be read and write");
        File sdFile = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        //String path = sdFile.getPath() + File.separator + "DestPdf";
        String path = sdFile.getPath() + "/demos/file/tmp/test";
        File dirFile = new File(path);

        if (!dirFile.exists()) { // if file doesn't exist
            System.out.println("create file");
            dirFile.mkdir(); // create file
            System.out.println(dirFile.toString());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.toString();
}
```

I also add some permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

Here is my print out, i can see the root /storage/sdcard/demos/file/tmp/test

```
11-17 08:38:10.263 15501-15501/? I/System.out: can be read and write
11-17 08:38:10.263 15501-15501/? I/System.out: create file
11-17 08:38:10.264 15501-15501/? I/System.out: /storage/sdcard/demos/file/tmp/test
```

But i can't find the file from android device monitor
[image]

What step i miss it ? Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not trying to create a file but a directory.  Even three directories. So you should use mkdirs().

Comment: Sorry type error , it is folder and i try mkdirs() , it's no working.

Comment: if(!dirFile.mkdirs()){Toast(..... could not create directory...); return;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should replace

```
dirFile.mkdir();
```

to

```
dirFile.mkdirs();
```

Example:

```
if (!dirFile.exists()) { // if file doesn't exist
        System.out.println(dirFile.mkdir());
        System.out.println(dirFile.mkdirs());

    }
```

will yield false for the first [and no dir will be created], and true for the second, and you will have created /demos/file/tmp/test

mkdirs() also creates parent directories in the path this File represents.

javadocs for mkdirs():

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.

javadocs for mkdir():

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.

hope help you!

Comment: Hey , i try `dirFile.mkdirs();`, its no working . I'm still thanks for your help.

Comment: Prety bad code. You should check the return value of mkdirs() and not use it in a log statement.

Comment: Update my response , i try it and i can see the folder now. Thanks your help bro.

Comment: @greenapps:thank for your comment ,use retern value  in a log statement just to find the problem quickly, normally it's bad code,but a quick way to find the problem;

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few months ago.

In my case the file was there, but windows couldn't see it (or the integration between adb and windows explorer).

Resetting the MOBILE was the only solution I found... After the reset the file was there in Windows Explorer.

I recommend you to try to find your files using the cli command:

```
adb shell ls sdcard/"your_path"
```

Also, try to create it using:

```
.getAbsolutePath()
```

Like this:

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "YOUR_FOLDER_NAME");

if(!path.exists()) 
{
    path.mkdirs();
} 
else 
{ 
    Log.d ("TAG","Path already exists");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I try restart my Android Studio , and open android device monitor again. Can't find the folder i create.

Comment: Hey thanks for your edited answer, its a good suggestion for me , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Android 6+ you need to add code to ask the user to confirm the permissions you asked in manifest.

Google for runtime permissions.