# Create folder failed when root is

Tags: android

Thanks for others help , i can create folder succeed now.

But i get a strange issue if android emulator doesn't has sdcard, i can't create the folder.

I can't figure it out..

Here is my code:

```
try {
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                    .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                System.out.println("can be read and write");
                File sdFile = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                //String path = sdFile.getPath() + File.separator + "DestPdf";
                String path = sdFile.getPath() + "/DestPdf";
                File dirFile = new File(path);

                if (!dirFile.exists()) {// if folder doesn't exist
                    System.out.println("create file");
                    dirFile.mkdirs();// create file
                    System.out.println(dirFile.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.toString();
        }
```

If my android emulator has sdcard root, i can create the folder `DestPdf`:
[image]
If there is no sdcard , i print the root is `/storage/emulated/0/DestPdf`, i create the folder failed, the folder `emulated` has nothing...
[image]

Any help would be appreciated .  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dirFile.mkdirs();`Half an hour ago i suggested you to change that to `if(!dirFile.mkdirs()){Toast(..... could not create directory...); return;} `. You should check the return value and handle accordingly! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346490/create-file-failed-from-mkdir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your app Internal Package folder for saving data,

```
 context.getFilesDir().getPath()
```

context is here Activity instance.Ok?

Do with it..

Comment: Awesome ! It can be created now. Though it will create under my apk.  Thanks you very much.

Comment: Thankyou Soo much